# i have problem with {useDrawerProgress} Hook in react drawer navigator it is not working?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to make Drawer menu screen transitions but the animation don,t work and I think the problem is  {useDrawerProgress} Hook but am not sure,  This is my custom-Drawer code

```
 function StackScreens({ navigation }) {
  const progress = useDrawerProgress();

  const scale = Animated.interpolateNode(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.8],
  });

  const drawerAnimationStyle = {
    transform: [{ scale }],
  };

  return (
    <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1, ...drawerAnimationStyle }}>
      <ScreenStack.Navigator>
        <ScreenStack.Screen
          name="HomeScreen"
          options={{ headerShown: false, animation: "slide_from_bottom" }}
          component={HomeScreen}
        />
        <ScreenStack.Screen
          name="Chapters"
          component={ChapterScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            animation: "slide_from_right",
            presentation: "modal",
          }}
        />
        <ScreenStack.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            animation: "slide_from_right",
            presentation: "modal",
          }}
        />
        <ScreenStack.Screen
          name="Setting"
          component={SettingScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            animation: "slide_from_right",
            presentation: "modal",
          }}
        />
      </ScreenStack.Navigator>
    </Animated.View>
  );
}
```

This my Drawer-Navigator Components am using react-navigation 6 and all the dependencies are the latest versions

```
export const DrawerNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={(props) => {
          return <DrawerContent {...props} />;
        }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Home"
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            swipeEdgeWidth: 50,
            drawerType: "slide",
            overlayColor: "transparent",
            drawerStyle: {
              width: "50%",
              backgroundColor: "transparent",
            },
            sceneContainerStyle: { backgroundColor: "transparent" },
          }}
        >
          {(props) => <StackScreens {...props} />}
        </Drawer.Screen>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

it just doesn't work I tried many ways but nothing works so please any help?

Comment: I solve it I just needed to spread the animation style

Comment: The progress never update its value properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71880702/custom-drawer-animation-with-react-navigation-using-usedrawerprogress)

But when I use

```
const scale = Animated.interpolateNode(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.7],
  });
```

it throws me error:
[error in android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAOc3.png)
So I'm using `progress.value` like this

```
  const scale = Animated.interpolateNode(progress.value, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.7],
  });
```

and the animation doesn't work!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).