# custom drawer animation with react navigation using useDrawerProgress()

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to achieve [this](https://youtu.be/NV48FIIWaN0?t=1387) animation with react navigation v6 where the Screen scales down when the drawer is opened.

Here's my code so far:

*App.js*

```
<Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
      initialRouteName="Home"
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={About} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

*Home.js*

```
const Home = ({ navigation, setProgress }) => {

  const progress = useDrawerProgress();

  const scale = Animated.interpolateNode(progress.value, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, 0.7],
  });

...

return (
    <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1, transform: [{ scale }] }}>

     ...

    </Animated.View>
```

However this doesn't work as expected, transform: scale doesn't change in the  ui. If I make some dummy changes to `Home.js` while the drawer in open the Home screen suddenly scales down.

I think the `const progress = useDrawerProgress()` doesn't updates the `progress`

Edit: Very similar to [this question](https://cdn.smileant.com/detail/ZYXWNWX.html) here

Answer (score 0):

Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Readonly<SharedValue> while trying to access drawerProgress.value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

`useDrawerProgress` update progress of opening drawer, but we need small rewrite logic of animation
try this:

```
import { interpolate, Extrapolate, useAnimatedStyles } from react-native-reanimated;

.
.
.

const drawerProgress = useDrawerProgress();
const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
  const scale = interpolate(drawerProgress.value, [0, 1], [1, 0.8], {
    extrapolateRight: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
  });
  const borderRadius = interpolate(drawerProgress.value, [0, 1], [0, 10], {
    extrapolateRight: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
  });
  return {
    transform: [{ scale }],
    borderRadius,
  };
});
```